# Uses cases for doctrine nested transactions

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm, doctrine, symfony4

I have a project where I need to do a transaction because I have 3 entities that depend on each other. Tenant, Organization, User.
First I started with a single transaction on one of the repositories and then I found out about doctrine nested transactions.
I didn't quite understand their role in doctrine and what are the use cases.
Can you explain me in more details than their documentation what are the use cases and if it applies to my case ?

In my case User requires an Organization id, Tenant id and Organization requires an Tenant id.
If on create one of the entities fails from some motive it should fail all three and rollback.

LE: I'm using doctrine with symfony.

Example from documentation of a nested transaction:

```
<?php
// $conn instanceof Doctrine\DBAL\Connection
$conn->beginTransaction(); // 0 => 1, "real" transaction started
try {

    ...

    // nested transaction block, this might be in some other API/library code that is
    // unaware of the outer transaction.
    $conn->beginTransaction(); // 1 => 2
    try {
        ...

        $conn->commit(); // 2 => 1
    } catch (\Exception $e) {
        $conn->rollBack(); // 2 => 1, transaction marked for rollback only
        throw $e;
    }

    ...

    $conn->commit(); // 1 => 0, "real" transaction committed
} catch (\Exception $e) {
    $conn->rollBack(); // 1 => 0, "real" transaction rollback
    throw $e;
}
```

Comment: Not really sure why I got a -1 to this question since the code was copied from the docs and I was asking what woud be real world cases to use it like that. :-) but anyway this is SO so ... :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're working with Doctrine ORM (which you do not disclose in your question) I don't understand why you're working with transactions in this case.

If you define associations between your entities like

```
/** @Entity */
class User
{

 /**
 * @ManyToOne(targetEntity="Organisation", nullable=false)
 */
private $organization;
```

this already ensures that a User entity will only be persisted when an organization is set. If that's not the case an error is thrown and it's not persisted or rolled back.

So if you are able to define your associations in that fashion a transaction wouldn't be required.

A transaction would only be required in cases where you aren't able to define such a technical chain of associations. E.g. when a organisation and a user need to created together but there is no technical association between them.

Comment: Well I'm not really sure why there isn't an relation between the entities. ( Sounds logical ). Because I'm just doing some refactoring on the code written by a co-worker.

Comment: it's gonna be tough then to advise how to proceed here. nested transaction sounds like an incorrect use case here.